# AFMA_ReceiveMessage is not defined

Tags: android, admob

I am integrating AdMob in my android app. The code for the add part is pretty simple and almost straight from Google Developer's guide. I am trying to implement Interstitials. The ads are showing fine but I am getting this in stackTrace in red:

> E/Ads(21443): JS: Uncaught ReferenceError: AFMA_ReceiveMessage is not defined (null:1)

Can anyone tell me what it means? Is it ok to release the app with this error as it doesn't crash the app?

EDIT: I just noticed that this error is being received for a specific ad and not for the other(just getting two ads in my country for now). So maybe it's just something missing from Publisher end.

Answer (score 9):

If this is the testing device you should call `AddTestDevice("your tester device code you can got it from logCat when you start the App")`.
If not it should work fine in the production environment.

Tester :

```
AdView mAdView = (AdView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.adView);
Builder adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice("3F166F686479332267DD2DCCD89dfwrg");
AdRequest aaa=adRequest.build();
mAdView.loadAd(aaa);
```

Production:

```
AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Comment: although it is started earlier and thus
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR).build();

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to create a thread to load Ads.

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            here your code to load banner ...
        }
    }).start();
```

For more documentation go to android developer's documentations on threads: 
http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html

If it returns error asking you to use main UiThread use following code in your Activity

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    interstitialAd.show();
                }
            });
```

Comment: whats the point of  adding a new Runnable to run on UI thread? its the same thing as executing your code in the main thread !

Comment: I agree with aimiliano.  Using runOnUiThread, post or postDelay is not helping if you are already on the UI thread which is required to load Ads.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue until I add

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.8.0'
```

in build.gradle. This solve the issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have created separate Ad Unit ID for interstitial ad request. If you use banner Ad Unit ID for interstitial request, this exact same error happens. It was working before that way, but they have changed it at some point.

Answer (score 1):

I got this particular error in stacktrace, because i didn't use ad listener for my adview.

Hope it helps someone.

```
yourAdView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAdClosed() {
        super.onAdClosed();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAdFailedToLoad(int i) {
        super.onAdFailedToLoad(i);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAdLeftApplication() {
        super.onAdLeftApplication();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAdOpened() {
        super.onAdOpened();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAdLoaded() {
        super.onAdLoaded();
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

I received this error when I hadn't completely set up my Ad unit ID (I had created it but not pressed the 'done' button). After finishing the setup on apps.admob.com, the error disappeared.