# interstitial ad show black (->) AFMA_ReceiveMessage is not defined (:1)

Tags: android, admob

I followed the [official guide of Android to add interstitial ads](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/interstitial).

If I use test mode:

```
 AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                  .addTestDevice("my code here")
                  .build();
 mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Works ok and I can see the demo interstitial add.

If I use release mode:

```
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);
```

I only see black interstitial add and in log in red:

> JS: Uncaught ReferenceError: AFMA_ReceiveMessage is not defined (:1)

**+ Info:**

- I use last updated google play services lib.
- I try with 2 devices and 2 wifi networks.
- In the same device I can see other apps interstitial ads
- The ad was created in adMob in last 24 hours.
- I try to [load add fron thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21119062/afma-receivemessage-is-not-defined) but app crash
- My adMob account is ok, I have other ads working.

Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

(...)

```
  <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
```

Activity OnCreate:

```
 mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
    mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("here my add id");
    mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdClosed() {

            requestNewInterstitial();

        }
    });

    requestNewInterstitial();
```

In app natural break:

```
 if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
           mInterstitialAd.show();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been solved just waiting 22 hours since the creation of ad in AdMob.

Comment: i also, but now facing new issue on 5.0+ device and that is error code 2 !

Answer (score 0):

Does webview in your activity?
Please comment code:

```
//webview.pause();
```

And It works.

Comment: No, my project does not use webview.