# Receiving E/Ads: JS: Uncaught ReferenceError: AFMA_ReceiveMessage is not defined (:1)

Tags: android, admob

As described, I am receiving the above error when intgrating AdMob in my app. I have of course checked out [AFMA_ReceiveMessage is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21119062/afma-receivemessage-is-not-defined) (which appears not to have a specific solution), I checked out [interstitial ad show black (->) AFMA_ReceiveMessage is not defined (:1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34623597/interstitial-ad-show-black-afma-receivemessage-is-not-defined-1) (but my ad is already about 20hrs old), I checked [AdMob: AFMA_ReceiveMessage is not defined (:1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38252415/admob-afma-receivemessage-is-not-defined-1) (not having an answer) and I checked [AFMA_ReceiveMessage is not defined using APPODEAL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34597340/afma-receivemessage-is-not-defined-using-appodeal) (not being the exact error I get). My code is as follows:

In the Manifest I requeest permissions:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

And I declare the activity:

```
        <activity
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
```

In my Layout of the corresponding activity:

```
 <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_overview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
```

And the code in the activity's java code:

```
        AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest.Builder adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
            .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR);
    //           .addTestDevice("my device id");
    AdRequest request = adRequest.build();

    mAdView.loadAd(request);
```

I tried with the DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR as suggested [here](https://discussions.udacity.com/t/ads-not-being-displayed/181131) and I tried with my device id. I tried it again and again for the last approx. 20 hours and I'm getting crazy. Has anybody an idea where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Did you add this in your Activity java file ? MobileAds.initialize(getApplicationContext(), "your AppID");

Comment: Hi, I actually used an interstitial ad now which works fine. But thanks for your effort. I think I did not include this, but I am not 100% sure right now...

Comment: Add it to your Ad's Activity, also make sure the ad has been created 5+ hours, and update to latest sdk to make sure you don't miss anything .